# Why does the org html export use <b> and <i> but not <u>?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

The org html export uses `<b>` tags for `*bold*` text, and `<i>` tags for `/italic/` text, but doesn't use `<u>` tags for `_underlined_` text. Instead it inserts a `<span class="underlined">`. Why is that the case?

I'm aware that by the current [HTML standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u), the `<u>` tag should be used for "unarticulated annotation", not for underlining. But the same is true for `<b>` (the bring attention tag) and `<i>` (the idiomatic text tag). Funnily, `<b`> and `<i>` have good alternatives as `<strong>` and `<em>`, but those aren't use either...

Comment: Such a "why" question is likely better directed at the Org maintainers directly. Others, here, may only be guessing.

Comment: Probably historical reasons: what the implementer knew at the time of writing the code, what the standard was at that time, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it is historical (as I said in my comment), but you can change it if you'd rather do it differently. All of that is controlled by the variable `org-html-text-markup-alist` which by default is defined as follows:

```el
(defcustom org-html-text-markup-alist
  '((bold . "<b>%s</b>")
    (code . "<code>%s</code>")
    (italic . "<i>%s</i>")
    (strike-through . "<del>%s</del>")
    (underline . "<span class=\"underline\">%s</span>")
    (verbatim . "<code>%s</code>"))
  "Alist of HTML expressions to convert text markup.
   ..."
   ...)
```

It *is* a `defcustom` so you can use the customize interface to change elements of the alist.

As usual, you should read the doc string of the variable with `C-h v org-html-text-markup-alist`.